# How does Softlayer handle post-install scripts on Vsphere?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, vsphere

I am reloading for ESXi's hosts using slcli. Here is the example of the call: `slcli hardware reload <hwd_id> --postinstall <url_to_post_install_script>`. My post install script is not being executed after the reload. Since, these are ESXi's they have a different way of executing post install scripts. How do I make my post-install execute after the reload? I will attach my script that I want to run after boot.

```html
#!/bin/sh

esxcli vsan storage automode set --enabled=false >> ${logfile} 2>&1
esxcli vsan cluster leave >> ${logfile} 2>&1
esxcli vsan storage list|grep "Is SSD: true" -C5| grep "Display Name" |awk '{print $3}' | 
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "removing: [$line]" >> ${logfile} 2>&1 
    esxcli vsan storage remove -s $line >> ${logfile} 2>&1
    sleep 10
done

echo "VSAN cleanup script has finished" >> ${logfile} 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your script will not be executed after reloading, Vsphere has a different system which is not supported by post-script feature.

Supported systems are listed here https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/provisioning-scripts.